# CSS transition not working when adding class via jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am adding a class to show an image when the mouse is over a div, but the transition isnt working at all.
I am using opacity, I know that the visibily: hidden is not animable.

The code is in the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#trigger").on("mouseenter", function () {
        $("#imgPuffo").addClass("visible");

        $("#trigger").on("mouseout", function () {
            $("#imgPuffo").removeClass("visible");
        });
        
    });

});
```

```css
#trigger {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
    img {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: opacity 2s;
    }
    .visible {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        animation: opacity 2s;
    }
    .imgPuffo {
        height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trigger"></div>
    <img id="imgPuffo" class="imgPuffo" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/449-4499911_how-to-draw-papa-smurf-from-the-smurfs.png" alt="">
```

Comment: `visibility` IS animatable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion as animation is being used, but animation will look for an @keyframes sequence to tell it what animation to run. In fact it looks as though we don't need a full CSS animation in this case, just a CSS transition.

I've added `transition: all 2s` in case you want to transition anything else in future, like the scale, but if you just want to stick with transitioning opacity you could do `transition: opacity 2s` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#trigger").on("mouseenter", function () {
        $("#imgPuffo").addClass("visible");

        $("#trigger").on("mouseout", function () {
            $("#imgPuffo").removeClass("visible");
        });
        
    });

});
```

```css
#trigger {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
    img {
        opacity: 0;
        /* animation: opacity 2s; */
        transition: all 2s;
    }
    .visible {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        /* animation: opacity 2s; */
    }
    .imgPuffo {
        height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trigger"></div>
    <img id="imgPuffo" class="imgPuffo" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/449-4499911_how-to-draw-papa-smurf-from-the-smurfs.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use animations check the docs.  You need to use @keyframes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#trigger").on("mouseenter", function () {
        $("#imgPuffo").addClass("visible");

        $("#trigger").on("mouseout", function () {
            $("#imgPuffo").removeClass("visible");
        });
        
    });

});
```

```css
#trigger {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
    img {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: opacity 2s;
    }
    .visible {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;  
        
        transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    .imgPuffo {
        height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trigger"></div>
    <img id="imgPuffo" class="imgPuffo" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/449-4499911_how-to-draw-papa-smurf-from-the-smurfs.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a solution for css using a `:hover`, without jquery?

```css
#trigger {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
    
#trigger:hover + .imgPuffo {
  opacity: 1;
}

.imgPuffo {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 200px;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="trigger"></div>
<img id="imgPuffo" class="imgPuffo" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/449-4499911_how-to-draw-papa-smurf-from-the-smurfs.png" alt="">
```